# 'Like' functionality in FQL / Graph API / iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-like

Does anyone know the recommended way of creating a FaceBook 'likes' button using the iOS Facebook SDK and the Graph API or FQL.

It does not seem to be directly supported or at least I can't find out how to do this using the documentation.

One approach other people have used is to embed the button in a webview and I have found this:
http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

The strange thing is that I can't seem to post a like using the graph API or FQL. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to like a page is via the Facebook like button in html.  I'm almost certain there will never be any other way.  Thus, you would need to embed the Facebook like button inside a UIWebView.  If they made a graph API method for it, it would be abused by everybody and every developer would make the user like their app and their pages.

Comment: The Facebook iPhone App has a 'like' button that does not appear to be a Webview so I still think there is a way of doing it without the UIWebView.

Comment: The Facebook iPhone App is made by Facebook, they have access to do whatever they want.  For everybody else, it isn't possible to like pages.  You can, however, like a comment/photo/wall post via the API.

Comment: One further problem with the UIWebView is that the FB like URL does not accept an access_token. This means that if single sign on is enabled the user will have to login twice as the UIWebView has no knowledge of the FB cookies outside the app sandbox.

Comment: Yes that is the bummer about the like button.  Although if they are logged into Facebook through Safari they shouldn't have to.  Like buttons aren't really a good fit for iOS apps.